# $X $~ $exp (0.5)$ and $Y$ ~ $exp (1)$. How can I calculate such probability?

Tags: probability

$X$ ~ $exp (0.5)$ and $Y$ ~ $exp (1)$. 
X is the waiting time for the bus and Y is the waiting time for the taxi. Meaning half a bus is expected to arrive every 1 hour and 1 taxi is expected to arrive every 1 hour.

It is know that in $\frac{1}{3}$ of the days I take the taxi and in $\frac{2}{3}$ I take the bus. What is the probability that in a random day I took the bus, if it is known that I waited less than $1.2$ hours overall?

I first calculated $P(X < 1.2)$ but now I am not sure how to continue. How can I calculate the probability that.overall I waited less than $1.2$ hours? If I have that then I think I can get the solution

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you're to compute $\Pr(X<Y|X<1.2)$.

Comment: Why? Can you explain please?

Comment: You take the bus if it arrives first (i.e. $X<Y$). And it's given that you wait less than 1.2 hours.

Comment: @yurnero : but $X < 1.2$ is not the same event than "waiting less than 1.2 hours". I would rather calculate $P( X < Y | \min (X,Y) < 1.2 )$

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track: the probability $P(X<Y|\min\{X,Y\}<1.2)$ is sought.

Set $A=\{\min\{X,Y\}<1.2\}$. By independence,
$$P(A)=P(X<1.2,Y<1.2)=P(X<1.2)P(Y<1.2).$$
Further, by the Law of Total Probability (disintegration),
$$P(\{X<Y\}\cap A)=\int_0^{1.2} P(X<y,X<1.2)dF_Y(y)=\int_0^{1.2} P(X<y)dF_Y(y),
$$
where $F_Y(y)$ is the c.d.f. of $Y$. At this point, explicit calculation of $$P(X<Y|A)=\frac{P(\{X<Y\}\cap A)}{P(A)}$$ is readily available.

Comment: $\min\{X,Y\}<1.2$ does not mean both are less than 1.2. Rather it means both cannot be greater. $$\mathsf P(\min\{X,Y\}<1.2) = 1-\mathsf P(X\geqslant 1.2)\mathsf P(X\geqslant 1.2)$$

Comment: Likewise. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y\cap\min\{X,Y\}<1.2)&=\mathsf P(X<Y, X<1.2)\\&=\int_0^{1.2} \int_x^\infty f_X(x)\,f_Y(y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_0^{1.2} f_X(x)\,(1-F_Y(x))\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$